# Bibliography Journal Names Not Italicized

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, sharelatex, elsarticle

I want the list of references within my bibliography to put the journal names in italics, as I feel that's standard practice; however, right now my entire reference is in plain text. I'm using the following:

```
\documentclass[authoryear, review, 12pt]{elsarticle}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
```

Comment: Make sure that your references suit the chosen bibliography style.

Answer (score 1):

When using a house style for submission to a journal -- such as `elsarticle` or (one of those provided in) `revtex` -- there's no point overriding the defaults.  You efforts will probably be undone and just serve to irritate the journal staff.

These house templates aren't a good idea for anything but submission to their intended journals, as they do strange things and are hard to customise. The standard `article` template will give you the italics you want but isn't suitable for submitting to elsevier journals (I assume, I haven't had much to do with them).

Comment: Ok, I see your point.  If that's the default in this bibliography style, I suppose I'll just leave it.  It appears whatever I choose will just get changed at the editorial stage anyway.